# Do not recognize element`s type in SOAP::Lite

Tags: asp.net-web-api, wsdl, soaplite

I try to call WebApi (ASP.Net) from SOAP::Lite lib (perl) by passing WSDL URL via method 'service':

```
<code>
   use SOAP::Lite;
   SOAP::Lite->new->service( 'http://....wsdl' )->_call( 'method', @params );
</code>
```

I have recieved answer, but all elements in response are processed as 'string', but not else;
For example, I expect `1` or `0` for bool types, but get strings `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, SOAP::Lite does not support wsdl properly(does not process response schema from wsdl). So, only one way exists to correctly cast response data: to include type attribute in server-side. IMHO.

Fortunately, I have used [XML::Compile](http://perl.overmeer.net/xml-compile/) lib by Mark Overmeer and recieved desired results.
In my opinion, [XML::Compile](http://perl.overmeer.net/xml-compile/) is more serious solution.